# Not able to find the correlation for the second iteration & same observed in UI as well

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, correlation, jmeter-5.0

We have a case in which we are unable to retrieve the correlated value from the second iteration; I placed that call in a single controller; I am able to write correlated value a to file; however, when we execute the script we are encountering the issue that the file is not found.

i tried multiple ways to save to a variable & used same values for the next iterations but not able to solve the issues. please help on handling of correlated value when it doesn't found from the second iteration

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to provide a comprehensive answer without knowing how exactly you're extracting the value and how you're writing it into the file. You're supposed to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

In general [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values are preserved across iterations so there is no need to write it into the file.

It might be the case you placed your Post-Processor not properly (see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for more details) and next Sampler simply overwrites the value with the empty or default one.

You can use [Debug Sampler or Debug Post-Processor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) in combination with View Results Tree listener, this way you will be able to see the variables values on each step of your test, this way you can localize the issue and identify which test element sets or unsets the value.

Answer (score 0):

Need to fetch all the correlatred values by passing as -1 at match no for regular expression

Use below code via JSR223 sampler:

```html
def cnt = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("oid_matchNr"));

def value="";

for(int i=1;i<=cnt;i++)
{
    domain += vars.get("oid_"+i) +","
}

vars.put("value",value);
```

then use place ${domain} at dummy sampler at once only controller ..then use regular expression extractor